# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' - - -

Tags: python, odoo-12

I am trying to filter based on date range, I want to replace dates that are not within the date range with another date, the function works as if fetch the date from hr.leave table if it found the date from smaller the date from of the wizard it replaces it the wizard date from, following logic for the date to

here is my function :

```
def _all_date(self, start_date, end_date):
    start_date = fields.Datetime.from_string(start_date)
    end_date = fields.Datetime.from_string(end_date)
    ######### get_all_leave_without filtering ##################
    leave = self.env['hr.leave'].search([])
    ######### search leave by leave##############
    for rec in leave:
        ###### condition if date_from of the leave < date_from of the wizard replace with wizard ######
        if rec.date_from < start_date:
            rec.date_from = start_date
        else:
            rec.date_from = rec.date_from
        if rec.date_to > end_date:
            rec.date_to = end_date
        else:
            rec.date_to = rec.end_date
```

when I called the function as following:

```
def generate_date(self,data):

    #### calling the function #####
    self._all_data(data['date_from'], data['date_to'])
```

I get an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\python\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 304, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\python\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 292, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\service\server.py", line 434, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\service\wsgi_server.py", line 142, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\service\wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 1320, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 1293, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\python\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\middleware\shared_data.py", line 220, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 1488, in dispatch
    result = ir_http._dispatch()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\auth_signup\models\ir_http.py", line 19, in _dispatch
    return super(Http, cls)._dispatch()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\web_editor\models\ir_http.py", line 22, in _dispatch
    return super(IrHttp, cls)._dispatch()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\http_routing\models\ir_http.py", line 403, in _dispatch
    result = super(IrHttp, cls)._dispatch()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 212, in _dispatch
    return cls._handle_exception(e)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 182, in _handle_exception
    return request._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 776, in _handle_exception
    return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 208, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 835, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 120, in wrapper
    raise ValidationError(tr(registry._sql_error[key], 'sql_constraint') or inst.pgerror)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 71, in tr
    lang = ctx and ctx.get('lang')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' - - -
```

Comment: I think something went wrong with configuration outside your code. Variable `ctx` in `server\odoo\service\model.py` should be obviously `dict` or something like, but it is a `str`. This problem masks real error probably.

Comment: but I didn't  change anything in the configuration